# Xcode Instruments 8.3 Display Settings button missing

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

In the latest version of Instruments 8.3 the display settings button has been removed and replaced by the File->Record settings dialog.

When using the allocation tools I now can no longer activate Automatic Snapshotting, because the option is gone from the right panel and the record options dialog is only showing the value for the allocation tool but not for the vm tracker. [Record options dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNT8V.png)

Does anybody know where the option has been moved to?

Many thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Many of the display settings have been moved to the bottom of the trace document window. To answer your question about automatic snapshots for the VM Tracker instrument, start by selecting the VM Tracker instrument from the instrument list.

At the bottom of the trace document window is a Snapshots button. Click the button and a popover opens for you to turn on automatic snapshots.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, missed the buttons down there.