# Time Profiler In Xcode Missing Record Settings, Display Settings

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, instruments, xcode-instruments

Im using Instruments 8.3.2 and the Record Settings and Display Settings tab are missing in the inspector window. How do I get those tabs back? Please see the attached screenshot.

[image: Instruments Xcode 8]

The normal inspector window looks like this (See arrow 5):

[image: Instruments Xcode 7]

Comment: Very related: [Xcode Instruments 8.3 Display Settings button missing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43477404/2415822).  The answer there helped me find the missing settings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The majority of these settings have moved to the bottom of the Instruments window.  Tap on "Call Tree" to see a modal with the missing settings:

[image: Call Tree]

Answer (score 1):

No With Xcode 9.3 & Instruments 9.3

The "Recording Options" moved again. 
Now it is in the app menu at **File** > **Recording Options…**.

Or you can use shortcut: <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Opt</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>

Or long press the **Record** button, it will appear options contains Recording options

You can see the menu item in the picture below:

[image]