# Where are Instruments options in Xcode 8.3+?

Tags: xcode, instruments

According to [Xcode Instruments 8.3 Display Settings button missing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43477404/1292061), many of the options previously present in the right-side "record settings" pane in Instruments 8.2.1 have moved to the bottom bar. However, I consistently seem to be missing settings that were previously present.

As a specific example, take the Points of Interest instrument (see [Alternative to DTSendSignalFlag to identify key events in Instruments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19017843/1292061) for details on its use). Here is a blank template to which the Points of Interest instrument has been added in Instruments 8.2.1:

[image: Instruments 8.2.1]

Note the options in the bottom-right pane, like "Color using last argument." Here's the same setup with Instruments 8.3.3:

[image: Instruments 8.3.3]

As far as I can tell, those options are gone. This is also the case for beta versions of Instruments 9.0. Where are those options hiding, or have they been removed entirely, just a year after [their introduction](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/411/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, under File > Recording Options:

[image]

Apple [called out this move](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW160) very strongly when it was made.

Comment: Knowing now where to look, one can find the callout in [Xcode 8.3 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW160).

Answer (score 3):

It's obnoxious how non-discoverable this is, but you can get to Recording Options by holding down the Option key while clicking on the Record button.

Comment: Kind of harsh. File > Recording Options. Not really all _that_ undiscoverable.

Comment: Thanks! Giving the check to the other answerer, who wins the FGITW race this time.

Comment: Though in truth, Charles Srtska is the last person I would want to get into a gunfight with, as he's a famous Pacifist.

Comment: @matt: I had the same "what the heck?" reaction as ravron the first time I fired up Instruments 8.3. On first glance, it really does look like the options have been removed. Not my favorite change.

Comment: @ravron: I fired up Instruments first to make sure I was remembering correctly about it being the Option key rather than Command(⌘). Unfortunately, I had a large compile going on in the background, causing Instruments to bounce for a while before launching, which slowed down my quick-draw (or Quartz, these days, I should say) a bit. :-P